# How to sort out comments on comments in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to provide my website visitors the facility to post comment on an existing comment, as we can post comment on an answer in stackoverflow.

Here I have created two tables

```
threads
    thread_id (auto increment),
    title VARCHAR(MAX),
    body VARCHAR(MAX),
    date datetime,
    user INT

comments
    comment_id INT (auto increment),
    parent_id INT,
    thread_id INT,
    title VARCHAR(MAX),
    body VARCHAR(MAX),
    date datetime,
    user INT
```

When User will Post the Comment on a thread it will be saved as below in comments table

```
comment_id = 1211
parent_id = NULL
thread_id = 122
title = "This is the title of the comment"
body = "This is the Body of the comment"
date = 2013-04-04 13:05:44
user = "xyzuser"
```

suppose a user post a comment on the above mentioned comment, that comment will be saved as below in comments table

```
comment_id = 1212
parent_id = 1211
thread_id = 122
title = "This is sample title of comment on comment"
body = "This is the Body of comment on comment";
date = 2013-04-04 15:05:44
user = "abcuser"
```

I am using the following query to fetch a thread from threads table

```
SELECT * FROM threads WHERE thread_id = 122
```

Till Now, I am getting the comments under the thread from the comments table as below

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE thread_id = 122
```

But Now, I also want to show the comments under each comment, 
I have tried following

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE thread_id = 122 GROUP BY parent_id
```

But using this query what will happen to the rows having NULL value in parent_id, and How I will sort out the comments under each comment.

Any One has any solution?? Which Query Should I use and How to sort out the comments under each comment??

Comment: Hi Rashid, you should take a look at this chapter extracted from the book "Sql Antipatterns". It does provide great insight in this common problem. http://media.pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/trees.pdf Cheers

Comment: It is a very handy book indeed. My pleasure

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.* FROM comments c
LEFT JOIN
  comments s
ON 
  s.parent_id = c.comment_id
WHERE c.thread_id = 122
GROUP BY c.comment_id
ORDER BY c.date ASC
```

Comment: `sort by` ?! You mean `order by` ?

Answer (score 0):

The query you used `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE thread_id = 122` will already also get your the comments under the comments. Are you  trying to get them in a specific order ? Then try adding `order by parent_id`. Or specify what order you want them in.

May be you can even draw up a small record set showing us how you want the query result to look like. Because I don't exactly understand how you want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you get the comment sql result whether array or object, say if array -

```
$comments = array(
    array('comment_id' => '1211',
        'parent_id'  => NULL,
        'thread_id'  => '122',
        'title'      => 'This is the title of the comment',
        'body'       => 'This is the Body of the comment',
        'date'       => '2013-04-04 13:05:44',
        'user'       => 'xyzuser'),
    array('comment_id' => '1212',
        'parent_id'  => '1211',
        'thread_id'  => '122',
        'title'      => 'This is the title of the comment',
        'body'       => 'This is the Body of the comment',
        'date'       => '2013-04-04 15:05:44',
        'user'       => 'abcuser'),
);
```

Now sort the array -

```
$childs = array();
foreach ($comments as &$comment) {
    $childs[$comment['parent_id']][] = &$comment;
}
unset($comment);

foreach ($comments as &$comment) {
    if (isset($childs[$comment['comment_id']])) {
        $comment['childs'] = $childs[$comment['comment_id']];
    }
}
unset($comments);

$tree = $childs[NULL];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($tree);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [comment_id] => 1211
            [parent_id] => 
            [thread_id] => 122
            [title] => This is the title of the comment
            [body] => This is the Body of the comment
            [date] => 2013-04-04 13:05:44
            [user] => xyzuser
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [comment_id] => 1212
                            [parent_id] => 1211
                            [thread_id] => 122
                            [title] => This is the title of the comment
                            [body] => This is the Body of the comment
                            [date] => 2013-04-04 15:05:44
                            [user] => abcuser
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

You can apply the same logic for object as well to display result in sorted order.